# Different behavior in Laravel Homestead & Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-forge, php-7.1

I had a simple mistake in my PHP Code:

```
$string += 'something' . $Car->id . ',';
```

Which resulted in different behavior in Homestead and Forge:

Homestead Result of $string:

> 0

Forge Result:

> Error: A non-numeric value encountered

Does Anybody know why? And how can I change the Homestead behavior to the same like the forge one? It's absolutely better..

---

Update

I'm sorry I wasn't totally clear in my question. The question wasn't about the mistake itself += instead of .=, I was aware of that.

The question is why in one environment the error appears and in the other one not.

Both environments are configured the same way (php.ini):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

And it was not just a notice, it's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Version of Laravel Homestead was 7.0.8 and the PHP Version of Laravel Forge 7.1.0-3.

I updated Laravel Homestead to the newest which uses PHP 7.1.0-2, and now Homestead shows up the right error:

```
Error: A non-numeric value encountered
```

I'm not shure if it's just the PHP Version or if it's an other change in Homestead with the new version. Thats just what I've found out.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because of the `+=` operator. That is used to add numbers together, whereas you're trying to concatenate strings.

You should be using `.=`

```
$string .= 'something' . $Car->id . ',';
```

or alternatively:

```
$string = $string . 'something' . $Car->id . ',';
```

The reason you're seeing that message in forge is because it seems to have PHP warnings turned on.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` adds a number (right value) to a variable's value (left value) and stores it in the variable.

Since your code of

```
$string += 'something' . $Car->id . ',';
```

has `$string` as the left value and contains non-numeric characters, hence the error. You probably meant `.=` which concatenates a string (right value) to the value of a variable (left value) and stores it in the variable.